# How to get external IPs of specific instance group on GCE - Google Compute Engine?

Tags: google-compute-engine, gce-instance-group

```
$ gcloud --format="value(networkInterfaces[0].accessConfigs[0].natIP)" compute instances list
```

This command currently works to get ALL the ips that are active but if I have multiple instance groups lets say one is called: Office, and the other is called Home

How do I get just the instance IPs in instance group "Office" only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no easy way to do it. Ideally it should be part of gcloud **instance-groups list-instances** API, but it does not return IP addresses, just instance names.

So far, I've managed to get the desired response by executing 2 different commands.

1. To get names of all instances

`instances=$(gcloud beta compute instance-groups list-instances <Enter Your Instance Group Name Here> | awk -v ORS=,  '{if(NR>1)print $1}')`

2. To get External IPs

`gcloud --format="value(networkInterfaces[0].accessConfigs[0].natIP)" compute instances list --filter="name=( $instances )"`

*A breakdown / explanation of 1st Command:*

- `gcloud beta compute instance-groups list-instances <Enter Your Instance Group Name Here>` will return all instances in that Instance Group
- `awk -v ORS=,` will replace all lines with , and returns a single comma separated string
- `'if(NR>1)` will exclude first line of response which is NAME
- `print $1` will get only the 1st column which
  are instance names
- `instances=$(<Entire Gcloud Command with awk)` will capture the response in variable

2nd Command should be self explanatory.

It will be great if someone can combine these 2 commands into a single command.